# Exporting all Informations flow out of a Diagram with Enterprise Architect

Tags: export, report, enterprise-architect

The Enterprise Architect keeps the connections of a Graph in the Database. 
I am looking for a way to export the information flows of a Diagram.

For this purpose i would need to sets of simple outputs:

1. A Matrix-View where the Names of the Elements are the X, Y-Axis and an X is drawn where they intersect
2. A List-View where all Information Flows are listed with their source and sinks.

I tried using a report, but i just could not get this to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're taking slightly the wrong approach here.

In Enterprise Architect, a diagram is not a *container* of information. It is a *display* which shows a selection of information from the underlying data store. This is in stark contrast with drawing tools, like MS Visio.

The EA data store is organized into packages, and that shows through the entire product. So if you edit an RTF document template, for instance, you will note that the internal template structure is based on a package structure -- it doesn't start from a diagram. You will also note that the context menu for a package or an element contains a Documentation sub-menu, but there isn't one in the diagram context menu. Same reason; a diagram is not a starting point for a document.

Now that said, you **can** create an RTF template which outputs only the information flows to/from the elements included in the generation scope, but you need to start off from a package and create your template based on a package structure. Setting up a table in a template is a little fiddly the first time but it's not impossible. In order to select only the information flows, use the Exclude Filters tab in the Generate Documentation dialog to exclude all connector types except Information Flow.

The matrix view you're looking for is known as a Relationship Matrix, located in the View menu (in EA 11.1). Again, it's based on a package structure, not a diagram structure. Relationship matrices can be included in generated documents as well.

Comment: Hi, basically what I would need is the information flows in a form A->B:"Information flow Notes". This can be done on a package structure, but i need that export in csv or text

Comment: Hm -- here it seems that you're taking slightly the wrong approach to Stack Overflow. This isn't a forum where we exchange posts in a thread, this is question and answer. The comment field is for requesting clarification, not to say "yes that's what I want can you do it for me?" which seems to be what you're doing. If, during the course of your work with getting to grips with your problem, you find that your question isn't really what you need to know, then delete it (unless you've accepted an answer already) and write a new one that's more relevant to the specific problem you're having.